# Counting unique number in python

Tags: python

I want count unique number in array that not sorted

```
def unique(l):
  X=[] 
  C=0
  for a in l:
    if a not in x:
      C+=1
      X.append(a)
  return c
```

I want my output be like this 
1 1 1
Out =0

But out is 1 not 0 and I don't know why.

Comment: Much easier: `numpy.unique(l).count()`, although this is not useful if `l` is very large.

Comment: or `len(set(l))` without numpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do:

```
def unique(l):
    return len(set(l))
```

Exactly as @YakymPirozhenko said in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Your code iterates through `range(l)`, which is the values `[0, 1, 2, ..., l-1]`. Try iterating through `l` instead:

```
def unique(l):
    x=[] 
    c=0
    for a in l:
        if a not in x:
            c += 1
            x.append(a)
    return c
```

Comment: And I don't want use function such as set () unique or count